# How do I get control of the fields of a existing Odoo module through javascript from a new module. I do not want to modify the existing module

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have a popup window in an existing module. This popup has fields. They aren't widgets that I can override.

```xml
<field name="lot_name" groups="stock.group_production_lot" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('lot_id', '!=', False),('lot_name', '=', False)]}"/>
```

I've inherited this existing module in a new module

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SerialGenerator(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move.line'

@api.onchange('lot_name')
    _logger.debug("###################### LOT NAME ######################")
    pass
```

The `onchange` fires correctly on the python side.

The problem is that I need to have javascript control over this field but because it's an existing field of an existing module that I do not want to modify I need to be able to access the field via the javascript in my new module sitting in

```
\mymodule\static\src\js\mymodule.js
```

Is what I'm attempting possible or is there a simple way I'm missing?

Comment: You can inherit the Javascript of Form View or Tree View.

Comment: Thanks @qvpham, I did exactly that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by inheriting the javascript from ListRenderer

```
odoo.define('mymodule.module', function (require, instance) {

var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
ListRenderer.include({
    events: _.extend({}, ListRenderer.prototype.events, {
        'click .classofinterest': '_newMethod',
    }),
    _newMethod: function () {
        // do stuff in javascript
    }
});

});
```